# C# lambda ref out

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, lambda

I'm trying to do this, but it doesn't work. Some suggestions?

```
int test_i = 0;
DoSomethingThatTakesAgesAndNeedsToUpdateUiWhenFinished(test_i);
test_i <- still is 0 and not 3!!!

public void DoSomethingThatTakesAgesAndNeedsToUpdateUiWhenFinished(int i)
{
    DisableUi();
    m_commandExecutor.ExecuteWithContinuation(
                () =>
                    {
                        // this is the long-running bit
                        ConnectToServer();
                        i = 3; <-------------------------- 
                        // This is the continuation that will be run
                        // on the UI thread
                        return () =>
                                    {
                                        EnableUi();
                                    };
                    });
}
```

Why I can't set test_i to 3? I also tried ref and out, but it doesn't work.

What can I do to fix it?

**EDIT**

I've tried this, but ouside of this method dataSet still is empty.

```
public static void Select(DataGridView dataGridView, ref DataSet dataSet, params object[] parameters)
  {
     var _dataSet = dataSet;
     AsyncCommandExecutor commandExecutor = new AsyncCommandExecutor(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current);
     commandExecutor.ExecuteWithContinuation(
     () =>
     {
        // this is the long-running bit
        _dataSet = getDataFromDb(parameters);

        // This is the continuation that will be run on the UI thread
        return () =>
        {
           dataGridView.DataSource = _dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        };
     });
     dataSet = _dataSet;
  }
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Hope it helps :o)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When passing the variable using the `ref` keyword, you can't use it inside a lambda expression. Try using a local variable inside the lambda and assign the `ref` variable outside it, if possible (somewhat simplified example):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    DoSomethingThatTakesAgesAndNeedsToUpdateUiWhenFinished(ref i);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}


public static void DoSomethingThatTakesAgesAndNeedsToUpdateUiWhenFinished(ref int i)
{
    int temp = i;
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        temp = 3; // assign the captured, local variable    
    });
    t.Start();
    t.Join();

    i = temp; // assign the ref parameter
}
```

**Update**
In response to the updated answer: your problem is that `_dataSet` inside the lambda expression is not the same variable as dataSet outside the lambda expression. What you could do is the following:

```
class DataSetContainer
{
    public DataSet DataSet { get; set; }
}
```

Now we have a reference type with a property that we can safely modify inside the lambda expression:

```
public static void Select(DataGridView dataGridView,
                          DataSetContainer dataSetContainer, 
                          params object[] parameters)
{
    AsyncCommandExecutor commandExecutor = new AsyncCommandExecutor(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current);
    commandExecutor.ExecuteWithContinuation(
    () =>
    {
        // this is the long-running bit
        dataSetContainer.DataSet = getDataFromDb(parameters);

        // This is the continuation that will be run on the UI thread
       return () =>
       {
           dataGridView.DataSource = _dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
       };
    });

}
```

}

In the above code, the lambda expression will update the `DataSet` property of the `DataSetContainer` instance that is passed to the `Select` method. Since you are not modifying the passed argument itself but only a member of that instance there is no need for the `ref` keyword, and we also get around the closure issue.

**Update 2**
And now when I switched on my brain, I realize that the `Select` method makes an asynchronous call. It is quite likely as the code looks that the last line is the `Select` method will be executed long before `_dataSet` is being assigned, and as a result it will be `null`. To get around this you probably want to look into using some sort of signaling mechanism (such as `ManualResetEvent` or `AutoResetEvent`) to know when the assignment is done.

Comment: Is it possible to use it like in my example but with a dataSet and not int i?

Comment: @Jooj: if you pass a reference type, you should be able to modify its member properties/fields inside the lambda expression.

Answer (score 8):

The `i` variable in the lambda expression refers to the parameter `i` of the method. As a workaround, you can make it to refer to a global variable (dirty solution).

By the way, [you can't capture `ref` and `out` variables in lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions/1365698#1365698), but you can have them as parameters. You need to change the signature of your delegate and the implementation of the method receiving the delegate, which might not be suitable:

```
(out int i) => { i = 10; }
```