# C# - How can I pass a reference to a function that requires an out variable?

Tags: c#, func, out, out-parameters

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoFoo()
    {
       int x;
       var coll = TheFunc("bar", out x);
    }

    public Func<string, int, ICollection<string>> TheFunc { get; set; }
}
```

Error: *"Argument 2 should not be passed with the 'out' keyword."*

```
public class Foo
{
    public void DoFoo()
    {
       int x;
       var coll = TheFunc("bar", out x);
    }

    public Func<string, out int, ICollection<string>> TheFunc { get; set; }
}
```

Error: *"Invalid variance modifier. Only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant."*

How do I get an out parameter in this function?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions for some details

Comment: FYI the more general rule here is that *a type argument must be a type which is convertible to object*. "out int" is not convertible to object; you cannot convert "reference to an int variable" to object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make your own delegate:

```
delegate ICollection<string> MyFunc(string x, out int y);
```

Answer (score 8):

Define a delegate type:

```
public delegate ICollection<string> FooDelegate(string a, out int b);

public class Foo
{
    public void DoFoo()
    {
       int x;
       var coll = TheFunc("bar", out x);
    }

    public FooDelegate TheFunc { get; set; }
}
```