# Mocking a COM+ wrapper with Moq is failing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, moq

I have a wrapper class for a COM+ Interface and I need to mock it.

This is the signature of that method on the Socket interface

```
int MakeRequest(object ServiceId, object Host, object Port,
                object Request, ref object pResponse);
```

And I'm using Moq to try mock it, like this

```
object pResponse = String.Empty;
var socket = new Mock<Socket>();
socket.Setup(x => x.MakeRequest(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(), 
                                It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>(),
                                ref pResponse))
            .Returns((int i, string s, int ii, string ss, object o) => 
            { 
                o = "Response";
                return 0;
            });
```

But for the 'o' arguments in the Returns I get

```
The value passed to the method is never used because it is overwritten in the 
method body before being read
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the `ref` keyword.  See these questions.  The second one has some attempts at this, though maybe they don't meet your needs.

[Cannot use ref or out parameter in lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions)

[Assigning out/ref parameters in Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068095/assigning-out-ref-parameters-in-moq)

If you can refactor to avoid use of `ref`, do that.  Else, hand roll a stub.

```
public class StubSocket
{
    int MakeRequest(object ServiceId, object Host, object Port, object Request, ref object pResponse)
    {
        pResonse = "Response";
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Refactoring was the only way to go