# Building expression tree throws NotSupportedException "TryExpression is not supported as an argument to method.."

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees

I'm trying to build an expression tree but it throws NotSupportedException when compiled:

> TryExpression is not supported as an argument to method 'Boolean TryGetMemberValue(System.Object, System.String, System.Object ByRef)' because it has an argument with by-ref type. Construct the tree so the TryExpression is not nested inside of this expression.

I sort of understand what it says but I can't figure out what I need to change... here's the code:

```
static void Main()
{
    //A.Child.Name
    var child = CreateExpression("Child", proxyParameter);
    var name = CreateExpression("Name", child);

    var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Proxy, object>>(name, proxyParameter);

    var func = expr.Compile();
}

class A
{
    public A Child { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

abstract class Proxy
{
    public abstract bool TryGetMemberValue(object parent, string name, out object result);
}

static ParameterExpression proxyParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Proxy), "proxy");

static Expression CreateExpression(string propertyName, Expression parent)
{
    var tryGetMemberMethod = typeof(Proxy).GetMethod("TryGetMemberValue");

    var result = Expression.Variable(typeof(object), "out result");

    var returnTarget = Expression.Label(typeof(object));

    var tryGetMember =
        Expression.Block(
            new[] { result },
            Expression.IfThenElse(Expression.Equal(Expression.Call(proxyParameter, tryGetMemberMethod, parent, Expression.Constant(propertyName), result), Expression.Constant(true)),
                Expression.Return(returnTarget, result),
                Expression.Throw(Expression.Constant(new MissingMemberException(propertyName)))),
            Expression.Label(returnTarget, Expression.Constant(null)));

    return tryGetMember;
}
```

Which generates the following expression:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Program+Proxy,System.Object]>(Program+Proxy $proxy) {
.Block(System.Object $'out result') {
    .If (.Call $proxy.TryGetMemberValue(
        .Block(System.Object $'out result') {
            .If (.Call $proxy.TryGetMemberValue(
                $proxy,
                "Child",
                $'out result') == True) {
                .Return #Label1 { $'out result' }
            } .Else {
                .Throw .Constant<System.MissingMemberException>(System.MissingMemberException: Child)
            };
            .Label
                null
            .LabelTarget #Label1:
        },
        "Name",
        $'out result') == True) {
        .Return #Label2 { $'out result' }
    } .Else {
        .Throw .Constant<System.MissingMemberException>(System.MissingMemberException: Name)
    };
    .Label
        null
    .LabelTarget #Label2:
}
```

Any ideas?

/* edited */
interestingly enough this works fine:

```
var tryGetMember =
    Expression.Block(
        new[] { result },
        Expression.Call(proxyParameter, tryGetMemberMethod, parent, Expression.Constant(propertyName), result),
    result);
```

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions/1365865#1365865)

Comment: Thanks @BartoszKP, saw that, however it doesn't explain the fact that if I remove Expression.IfThenElse the code works fine (see last edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the exception message is far from clear, I think you just encountered a limitation of the `Expression` compiler: you can't have complicated subexpressions under a call expression to a method with `ref` parameters.

I think what you should do to fix this is basically the same thing you would do in C# code: use a local variable to keep the intermediate result:

```
var child = Expression.Variable(typeof(object), "child");

var body = Expression.Block(
    new[] { child },
    Expression.Assign(child, CreateExpression("Child", proxyParameter)),
    CreateExpression("Name", child));

var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<Proxy, object>>(body, proxyParameter);
```

With this change, the code no longer throws an exception.

Also, you don't need to use `Label` and `Return` in your `tryGetMember` expression. Instead, you could replace `IfThenElse` with `Condition` (basically, ternary operator from C#). If you do this, you also need to specify the type of `Throw` (even though it never actually returns):

```
var tryGetMember =
    Expression.Block(
        new[] { result },
        Expression.Condition(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Call(
                    proxyParameter, tryGetMemberMethod, parent,
                    Expression.Constant(propertyName), result),
                Expression.Constant(true)),
            result,
            Expression.Throw(
                Expression.Constant(new MissingMemberException(propertyName)),
                typeof(object))));
```