# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type - OrderBy and DbGeography by ref

Tags: c#, linq

This fails with an error:

```
private IQueryable<Field> PrepareAllFieldsQuery( ref DbGeography geo, int page, int amount, string sort, string order, ISearchCriteria searchCriteria )
{
    var query = this.context.Fields
                            .Where( x => x.DeletedAt == null )
                            .OrderBy( x => x.GeoLocation.Distance( geo ) );
    ...
}
```

This runs fine

```
private IQueryable<Field> PrepareAllFieldsQuery( DbGeography geo, int page, int amount, string sort, string order, ISearchCriteria searchCriteria )
{
    var query = this.context.Fields
                            .Where( x => x.DeletedAt == null )
                            .OrderBy( x => x.GeoLocation.Distance( geo ) );
    ...
}
```

The difference is my `DbGeography` is not passed by ref this time.

Any reasons why the `.OrderBy( x => x.GeoLocation.Distance( geo ) );` function would throw the following error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I can't even compile it... *Cannot use ref or out parameter 'geo' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression*

Comment: This might [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions) seems to have the explanation.

Comment: @rdoubleui - This makes a lot of sense. Thank you man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is caused by funny things the overload resolution of C# is doing... It is trying to resolve your `OrderBy` to the Dynamic Linq "version" of `OrderBy`, that accepts a `string` as a parameter.

In general, a more correct error, and the one you get if you remove the `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` or if you rewrite the statement to force using `Queryable.OrderBy`, like:

```
var query = Queryable.OrderBy( this.context.Fields.Where( x => x.DeletedAt == null ),
                               x => x.GeoLocation.Distance( geo ) );
```

would be *Cannot use ref or out parameter 'geo' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, or query expression*. As pointed by rdoubleui, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions) there is an explanation for that.