# Implement calling delegate with out parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, decorator, out

I try to implement a decorator pattern for handling error in database transactions. I have no problem with standard Func and Actions, but i have difficulties with functions having *out* parameter.

Here many topics with same question, and i figured out to implement my own delegate:

```
    public delegate TResult FuncWithOut<T1, T2, TResult>(T1 arg1, out T2 arg2);
```

1) But i don't found how to implement method based on this delegate:

```
    private void SafetyExecuteMethod(Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Some handling
        }
    }

    private T SafetyExecuteFunction<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        T result = default(T);
        SafetyExecuteMethod(() => result = func.Invoke());
        return result;
    }

    private SafetyExecuteFunctionWithOut // ??
    {
        // ??
    }
```

2) And how to call this method:

```
    public bool UserExists(string name)
    {
        return SafetyExecuteFunction(() => _innerSession.UserExists(name));
    }

    public void CreateUser(string name, string password)
    {
        SafetyExecuteMethod(() => _innerSession.CreateUser(name, password));
    }

    public bool CanUpdateUser(string userName, out string errorMessage)
    {
        // ??
        // _innerSession.CanUpdateUser(userName, out errorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: 1) What exactly is the problem? Does it compile? What else? 2) There are three methods. Which?

Comment: 1) I don't know how to implement "SafetyExecuteFunctionWithOut" method. 2) And how to call this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same scheme as in your example of `SafetyExecuteFunction<T>(Func<T> func)`.

One thing you have to pay attention to is that you need to use a temporary local variable for the out parameter.

```
private TResult SafetyExecuteFunctionWithOut<T1, T2, TResult>(FuncWithOut<T1, T2, TResult> func, T1 arg1, out T2 arg2)
{
    TResult result = default(TResult);
    T2 arg2Result = default(T2); // Need to use a temporary local variable here 

    SafetyExecuteMethod(() => result = func(arg1, out arg2Result));

    arg2 = arg2Result; // And then assign it to the actual parameter after calling the delegate.
    return result;
}
```

Calling the function does then work like this:

```
public bool CanUpdateUser(string userName, out string errorMessage)
{
    bool result = SafetyExecuteFunctionWithOut<string, string, bool>(_innerSession.CanUpdateUser, userName, out errorMessage);
    return result;
}
```

Note, that you have to pass `_innerSession.CanUpdateUser` as a parameter to `SafetyExecuteFunctionWithOut` instead of using a lambda expression.

---

Using the naive attempt:

```
private TResult SafetyExecuteFunctionWithOut<T1, T2, TResult>(FuncWithOut<T1, T2, TResult> func, T1 arg1, out T2 arg2)
{
    TResult result = default(TResult);

    SafetyExecuteMethod(() => result = func(arg1, out arg2));

    return result;
}
```

creates the error message:

> CS1628    Cannot use ref or out parameter 'arg2' inside an anonymous
>   method, lambda expression, or query expression

Why you are not allowed to do that is [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365865/101087).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was very helpful!