# Out variables and nested lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-function

Just coding for a bit of fun and to get my head round anonymous methods, etc.  I have a class whose main purpose is to run a lambda in a loop.  The lambda has an out parameter (exit) which gets passed back into the class. Now I can nest these as per the code below where l2 is declared in the lambda for l1.

```
            int outer = 0;

            Loop l1 = new Loop().Infinite((out bool outerExit) =>
            {
                int inner = 0;
                outer++;

                Loop l2 = new Loop().Infinite((out bool innerExit) =>
                {
                    inner++;
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{outer}-{inner}");
                    innerExit = inner >= 3;
                    outerExit = inner >= 3;
                });

                //outerExit = outer >= 3;
            });

            Assert.Equal(3, outer);
```

However this gives an error in the l2 lambda where i assign a value to outerExit.

> Error CS1628  Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'outerExit' inside
> an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local
> function

The idea is to exit both Loops from within the inner loop when a certain criteria is met.

For those interested.

```
public class Loop
    {
        //this is a delegate TYPE!!! that matches our function
        public delegate void ExitableAction<T1>(out T1 a);

        //in thiscase it is a bool
        protected ExitableAction<bool> action;

        protected LoopType type;

        public Loop Infinite(ExitableAction<bool> actn)
        {
            action = actn;
            type = LoopType.Infinite;

            Start();

            return this;
        }

        protected void Start()
        {
            bool exit = false;

            while(!exit)
            {
                action.Invoke(out exit);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Sweeper added.

Comment: The error is very specific. You a lambda cannot have an `out` parameter

Comment: There's no need for them either because you have access to both of the variables corresponding to the these parameters because they are in scope. Closures for the win

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot use ref or out parameter in lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions)

Comment: So do you want it to output 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 and then stop? `outer`'s final value would be 1 then, not 3?

Comment: Remove the parameters themselves. Just a sign to the variables inside of the lambdas. They are in scope.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the Loop class runs the lambda in a loop unless you tell it to stop.  that is what the parameter is for.  A bit like a cancellation token.  If i remove the parameters, how would i pass the value back into the Loop?

Comment: the actual output is immaterial.  i just want to "leave" the outer loop from within the inner loop.

Comment: Can you define what "leave" means? Do you want to continue to run the remaining portion of the loop body (of either the inner loop or outer loop), and then stop, or stop immediately at that point? Depending on what kind of "leave" you want, the output will be affected, so clearly it is not immaterial...

Comment: @Sweeper ok.  i want it to finish that iteration of that loop/lambda and not run again.  Not immediately drop out.

Comment: @ThirdPrize as I thought :) My answer should hopefully work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *why* you can't use `ref`/`out` parameters, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions).

You seem to want to recreate a "loop" statement with a "break" functionality. Rather than using `out` parameters to implement the `break` statement, you can use another `Action<bool>` delegate instead.

```
public class Loop
{

    protected Action<Action<bool>> action;

    public Loop Infinite(Action<Action<bool>> actn)
    {
        action = actn;

        Start();

        return this;
    }

    protected void Start()
    {
        bool exit = false;

        while (!exit)
        {
            // passes the Action<bool> that assigns the given bool to exit
            action((b) => exit = b); 
        }
    }
}
```

```
int outer = 0;

Loop l1 = new Loop().Infinite(setOuterExit =>
{
    int inner = 0;
    outer++;

    Loop l2 = new Loop().Infinite(setInnerExit =>
    {
        inner++;
        Console.WriteLine($"{outer}-{inner}");
        setInnerExit(inner >= 3);
        setOuterExit(inner >= 3);
    });

    setOuterExit(outer >= 3);
});
```

This gives a final `outer` value of 3. But if you wanted that, you could have just removed the `setOuterExit` call in the inner loop - it also gives 3 as output.

Right now the value assigned to `exit` by the inner `setOuterExit` call is being "overwritten" by the outer `setOuterExit` call, so the outer loop doesn't break immediately when it hits the inner `setOuterExit`. We could change the assignment to `exit` to:

```
action((b) => exit |= b);
```

So that if `exit` is ever set to `true`, no other values can overwrite it. This will solve this problem, but note that `setOuterExit` still won't work the same as a real `break;` statement. The code immediately after `setOuterExit` still gets executed, for example.

Comment: @ThirdPrize yes, and instead we use the lambda capturing mechanism to set the `exit` variable.

Comment: See if i have got this right.  The parameter is no longer an "out" so the outer parameter can be referenced by the inner lambda.  Action<Action<bool>> is an action that returns an action that returns bool.   outerExit(outer >= 3) sets the sub action  to a bool value and passes it back.  action((b) => exit = b) calls the outer action and sets exit to the bool value that was passed back.  cunning.

Comment: @ThirdPrize I think you mostly understood correctly. The big misunderstanding is that `Action<Action<bool>>` represents a function that takes a parameter of type `Action<bool>`, which in turn represents a function that takes a parameter of type `bool`. `action((b) => exit = b)` calls the lambda you passed to `Infinite`, and setting `setInnerExit`/`setOuterExit` (which is a function that takes a bool parameter) to be the lambda that sets `exit` to that `bool` parameter. This way, when you call `setOuterExit(outer >= 3)`, you are actually doing `exit = outer >= 3`.