# Generic parameter type to use inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to create a method that accept generic parameter type like in Javascript.

Let says I have a List of `User` objects with `name` and `id` properties.

In Javascript , to search through the list using property value will be as simple as:

```js
class User{
    constructor(name, id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

let users = [
    new User("John",1),
    new User("Deer", 2),
    new User("Bruce", 3),
    ]

function findArr(arr, propertyName, propertyValue){
    for(let a of arr)
        if(a[propertyName] === propertyValue) 
            return a;
    return null;
}

console.log(findArr(users, "name", "Deer"))
console.log(findArr(users, "id", 3))
```

Then, I try to recreate this in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class User{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int id {get; set;}
}

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<User> Users = new List<User>{
            new User{name="John", id=1},
            new User{name="Deer", id=2},
            new User{name="Bruce", id=3}
        };
        
        int propertyValue = 2;
        var u = FindList<User, int>(Users, "id", ref propertyValue);
        Console.WriteLine(u.name + " " + u.id);
    }
    
    public static T FindList<T, K>(List<T> obj, string propertyName, ref K propertyValue){
        return (T)obj.FirstOrDefault(o=>
                (K)o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o, null) 
                == 
                propertyValue
            );
    }
}
```

But this will throw exception: `Cannot use ref, out, or in parameter 'propertyValue' inside an anonymous method, lambda expression, query expression, or local function`.

Why is this exception thrown?

How do I make this work?

Comment: Why do you need `ref`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, you cannot use the ref or out keywords in an anonymous function. This is by design, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365689/cannot-use-ref-or-out-parameter-in-lambda-expressions).

The good news is, you do not need to use ref at all. You can achieve what you want simply by passing the property value as a normal parameter, like so:

```
public static T FindList<T, K>(List<T> obj, string propertyName, K propertyValue){
    return (T)obj.FirstOrDefault(o=>
EqualityComparer<K>.Default.Equals((K)o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(o, null) , propertyValue));
}
```

Note that the equality check with == operator [won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390900/cant-operator-be-applied-to-generic-types-in-c) for unconstrained generic type in general, so we use the EqualityComparer method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a weakly typed language, every object is essentially just a dictionary.

If you ever find yourself accessing properties by name in C#, you're probably doing something "wrong".

Rather than using reflection, you could pass in a function to access the property;

```cs
    public static T FindList<T, V>(List<T> obj, Func<T,V> propertyAccess, V propertyValue){
        return obj.FirstOrDefault(o => propertyAccess(o) == propertyValue);
    }

var u = FindList<User, int>(Users, u => u.id, propertyValue);
```

However, I don't think this method really adds anything to your C# code. You'd be better off just writing the straight forward solution, without complicating anything with your own "helper" method;

```cs
var u = Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.id == propertyValue);
```

It's not the same as the javascript code you are familiar with. But you're writing in C# now. If you want to work with other C# programmers, you will need to change the way you think about programming problems.